# How to extract the minute of the day with R?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a column in `df1` that summarizes the datetime in format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" for several months. I would like to extract the minute of the day for each datetime. That is, for the time "00:43:43" the minute of the day would be "43", for the datetime "02:24:58", the minute of the day would correspond to "144". The minute of the day has to range between 1 and 1440.

I add the code to replicate the example:

```
df<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2019-07-03 00:43:43",  "2019-07-03 02:24:58"))
df$Datetime<- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime, formtat="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")

df
             Datetime
1 2019-07-03 00:43:43
2 2019-07-03 02:24:58
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `UTZ` should be `UTC` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is

```
library(lubridate)
round(period_to_seconds(hms(v1))/60)
```

If we don't want to `round` it

```
sub("\\..*", "", period_to_seconds(hms(v1))/60)
#[1] "43"  "144"
```

#### Update

In the OP's initial post, the format showed was `%H:%M:%S`, so we used `hms`.  With the example showed, it would be `ymd_hms`

```
v2 <- sub(".*\\s", "", df$Datetime)
sub("\\..*", "", period_to_seconds(hms(v2))/60)
#[1] "43"  "144"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("00:43:43",  "02:24:58")
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I applied your code but it didn't work. I guess it was due to the format, since I have the data as Posixct, concretely in "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%S". When I runned `df$Minute<-round(period_to_seconds(hms(df$Datetime))/60)` it gives you back `NA`.

Comment: @Dekike  It is the format.  In the post, you mentioned the format as HMS.  Here, you need `ymd_hms` instead of `hms`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `format` to format the datetimes into an expression and then evaluate it.

```
sapply(format(df$Datetime, '%H*60 + %M'), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))

# 00*60 + 43 02*60 + 24 
#         43        144
```